# Multilingual careers CVs

Tags: feature-request, jobs

**tl/dr** : Is it/will it be possible to fill out our Careers CV with localized information ?

Is it/will it possible to have different versions of the CV posted at careers (not totally different but just translated)?

Being in non English *oriented* country, this can be very helpful if I send local companies a link to my Careers CV and they could read it in a language other than English. LinkedIn has an implementation of this feature where you can create your profile in another language and it's up to the user to fill in the information in that language (first and last name, past experiences, etc)

The reason for this is primarily because my CV on careers contains more than just a list of bullet points, it reveals who I really am as a software developer (top tags, top answers, links to github projects, etc).

Comment: How come we don't we have this yet?

Comment: I don't really get it how this was not implemented. I want and need it.